# Pathfinding with voronoi

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have reached a dead-end with my university project and I can't find a way to solve. The problem is:

**Given a circular robot (green circle) with radius r
I need to find a path (any path not the best) to the end point which is the blue dot.**

***image below***

- The obstacles are the red polygons and around them the cyan lines
  represent the Minkowski sum.
- The black dots represent the voronoi diagram.
- The blue box around is the outside border

So first I though I should find the closer points to the start point (robot) and the end point of the voronoi diagram points. And those points are shown in the image (cyan dots).

Then I was thinking with some king of algorithm like the A* to search for the path for the cyan dots found above along the voronoi points, that way I will find the safest path sort of.

The problem is that I don't have a way of knowing which are the neighbors of each point in the voronoi diagram. Because as you can see in the some parts of the diagram there are big gaps.

[image]

So what do you suggest?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: is there any limit on the size of the map?

Comment: The blue polygon around the obstacles is the border. Its dimensions are something like 1000x700 pixels (depends on the window size).

Comment: so worst case scenario if you have no way to know nothing about the map is to go through all the points, just have to go to a top corner or bottom and start going from there scanning it all

if it was a map what worked best for me in the past is the rule of going always left following the walls, but on this case with irregular maps sometimes it's better to just go through all the points

Comment: So doing an A* algorithm for all the points?

Comment: unfortunately it's the one that probably will work the best for you, here you have a few alternatives http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html#paths

Comment: Given that this is a 2D motion planning problem with polygonal obstacles, you should be able to compute a visibility graph. Failing that, you could always just wing it with an RRT or PRM and it should do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a black and white image that represents your map. It should start as all black.
2. Render your obstacles as white.
3. Dilate the image using a circular filter the size of your circular robot.
4. Find the shortest path from A to B that only traverses black pixels.

[image: Pathfinding]

Comment: Really cool unique approach. How fast is this in practice? Did you consider visibility graphs or other traditional motion planning approaches (RRT, PRM, Potential Fields)?

Comment: I like this solution very much , although I have already solved the problem using visibility graph and A* search I am intersted to know if a similar approach to yours can be used for the next part of the problem which is a 2 dimensional robot that can rotate. If not can you recommend something thats relatively easy to implement?

Comment: @GeorgeP For example: Create N swept-rotated-robotshape filters for N different rotations to produce N navigation images (one for each range of rotations).  With N=8, you would generate a filter that corresponds to sweeping the shape representing your robot from 0 to 45 degrees, from 45 to 90, ..., from 315 to 360.  Then you can do a graph search to find a path, where you are able to jump between the N images as well (corresponding to robot rotation that crosses a multiple of 45 degrees boundary).

Comment: Can you provide me with something to read regarding that matter, because I have limited experience and I didn't understand much from your answer.Thank you

Comment: @GeorgeP This is my own invention, although I'm sure it's not original.  I tried searching around for people doing something similar and wasn't too successful.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I don't have a way of knowing which are the neighbors of each point in the Voronoi diagram. Because as you can see in the some parts of the diagram there are big gaps.

There's probably a better solution, but here's a simple algorithm you could try:

1. Find (or set manually) the longest distance between "connected" points, D.
2. Make a table of distances between each pair of points of your Voronoi diagram, where that distance is less or equal to D.
3. Connect all points starting with shorter distances, except if path shorter than D already exists between them (to avoid unnecessary small loops and cutting corners).
4. Find closest point to your robot and closest point to your destination.
5. Run shortest path algorithm on the graph you built in step 3.